# iPhone SDK : How to remove the horizontal markers from Core-Plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-plot

I have implemented core-plot in my iPhone app. I am using the gradient scatter plot as shown below:

[image]

How to remove the horizontal markers that appear on Y Axis of the graph in the above core plot?

Comment: i'm also want to do the same for my application.how can i implement core plot in my application.My task is to create chart application.please help me.Thank you

Comment: @iphonecool: Yeah sure. You can check my last 15 questions from my account here in stackoverflow and you will solve many of your problems regarding coreplot. Here all the others SO members have been very helpful in answering my questions when I was at the same stage as you are now. Anyways if you have particular doubts then you can ask me. I will be more than happy to help. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `majorTickLineStyle` and `minorTickLineStyle` properties to `nil`.